# Resources to learn the art of oral arguments in the courtroom

Tags: india, court, reference-request

Courts in India are hugely overburdened. It is common for a court (be it a trial court or High Court or the Supreme Court) to have more than a dozen cases listed before it each day.

Under these circumstances, it is difficult for judges to go through the filings in their entirety before the case comes up for hearing. The art of oral advocacy, therefore, becomes even more important than ever.

Could you suggest good resources (books, articles, video lectures, etc.) which may help one become better at oratory skills in the courtroom?

I am primarily interested in constitutional matters (rather than civil suits or criminal trials).